# Не могу получить PromiseResult из promise

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise

Делаю запросы применяя asyc await, которые возвращают promise из него мне нужно получить данные, но при попытке получить данные как из обычного объекта выдает undefined.[image: Массив с объектами(в каждом объекте данные которые нужно вывести на экран, но обернуты в promise, как от туда их достать)]

Comment: Приложите код пожалуйста.

Comment: а собственно ответ в обект переведен?

Comment: @Armen на скриншоте как раз массив из объектов, каждый объект это ответ

Comment: @AndreyChipizubov а данные ты пытаешся получить после того как обработаеш промис то есть в then ну или после await? всетаки если бы код было легче понять